# 3 connection low pressure faucet with regular hot water tank

Tags: sink, plumbing-fixture, hot-water

After purchasing a replacement all in one sink and new faucet to replace my laundry room sink, I had a look underneath and was surprised to see that there are 3  water connections to the faucet. This is the only faucet in the house that isn't a 2 connection high pressure faucet.

As far as I know there is nothing in my house that would necessitate it. My best guess is that the previous owner split the hot water supply under the floor and just connected it to both of the hot water connection points.

I have no boiler and if there is any sort of additional heating device other than my regular hot water tank it is hidden in walls and definitely not up to code (it also would make no sense for such a rarely used faucet). The centre connection is copper while the other two are PEX which is what is used for almost all of the plumbing in my house which further leads me to suspect this was something strange done by the previous owner to fit an incorrect faucet into place.

Any thoughts on what else might be going on or how I can best confirm what's going on without cutting into a bunch of walls and floors?

[image: pipes coming out of floor]
[image: connecting into tap]
[image: washer connections on wall to the left of sink]

Edit: Added some photos as requested. I think
crip659 is right and the tap is likely being used to link water to the washer's hot water connection. We have to do some laundry later the copper pipe is cold so I'm going to see if it heats up when the washer is run (without the sink tap being run.) to verify.

Edit 2: When the washer pulls hot water the copper pipe to the faucet doesn't get hot. I tried every fixture in the house with hot water running them until they got hot and the pipe didn't get hot. When I run the tap itself the pipe gets hot right away...

Comment: Pictures will help, but sounds like just using it to run water to somewhere else, instead of just adding a tee fitting to the water line going by.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that though I was thinking that if I connected them before going to the new faucet everything would sort of have to work itself out naturally. Might be the connection to the faucets for the actual washer. I'm on infinite hold about something else and only get reception upstairs will add photos when I can. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @crip659 As per my edit 2 running other fixtures doesn't seem to make the third pipe hot. My best guess at this point is back to the previous owner just connecting two hot water pipes. Am I correct to think that as long as I connect the two pipes it'll perform the same function as the tap and it won't really matter? I was thinking of getting some sharkbite adapters going from a T in the Pex to the copper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I researched a tap with 3 connections all I could find was [this](https://www.waschbeckenarmaturtest.de/en/faucet-connections/) which indicated that it was a low pressure tap.

Turns out that isn't the case the third connection is a trap seal primer (which I'd never heard of before).

After confirming the temperature of the copper pipe doesn't change when I run water through any other fixture I finally Googled the specific tap and realized it was a tap seal primer. I also now note that when I run hot water through the tap it gets hot and when I run cold water through the tap it gets cold as some of whatever water I'm running is going through that copper tube rather than it being specifically connected to one type of water.

I'll have to rethink my reno a bit as I don't think my replacement faucet supports a trap seal primer so I'll have to get a separate device of some sort installed.

Comment: Why would you need a trap seal primer?

Comment: The current tap has a trap seal connection so water flows into the trap seal any time I use the faucet. The new faucet I have to replace it doesn't have a trap seal hookup so I either can't use it or I need to install a trap seal primer.

Comment: Let me rephrase: What is the function of a trap seal primer? I've never heard of one.

Comment: When you have a P trap under a sink or shower drain it prevents sewer gas from coming into your house because of the water in the trap. Over time the water evaporates but whenever you run water down the drain that water replenishes the trap. If you have a trap somewhere that doesn't get a lot of water like the AC condensate drain you likely need a trap seal primer. Apparently it is normal to use the laundry sink for this. So whenever I run water through the laundry sink hot or cold a portion of it flows down to the trap in my basement. This is built into the faucet but devices are available.

Comment: That is something new. Come to think of it, I have a drain in my basement between the water heater and the well plumbing. It almost never gets any water in it, but we've never had any problem with sewer odor. It makes me wonder if it's connected to the septic system at all. Thanks @David Oldford!

Comment: No problem. My guess is that there is a trap seal primer somewhere. I had never heard of it until now when I am trying to replace my laundry sink. It would likely have been a code requirement. My house was built in the early 2000s so at least up until then the faucet method was the most common apparently.

Comment: @RetiredATC Looking into my situation further I found out that water based traps are now unusual in new builds. Apparently now new houses are built with spring based trap seals something like this one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-3-in-Seal-Drain-for-Showers-and-General-Purpose-43747/315169793#overlay

Comment: Again, I learned something useful today. Thanks @David Oldford

Comment: no problem @RetiredATC. One additional note that specific item I linked to works like the device the plumber I hired put into my drain for me but it is very cheap both in terms of price and performance compared to it. I picked one up for another rarely used drain and will be returning it. My understanding is the good ones use springs that one is just sort of soft rubber that falls open from the top but not the bottom.

Comment: @DavidOldford please be sure to click the check mark next to your answer so others know it's been resolved. That will save people time reading through it looking to answer it, and will help others with a similar problem find this as a suitable answer.